# Liferay: how to delete email id reserved while creating user

Tags: liferay

Liferay 6.1:

i am trying to change the existing email id with new email id but 
it was giving me error saying "email is reserved" i deleted this account and tried to create but same error persisted.

how to delete a reserved credential like email or screen name once you reserve the credentials in the users of portal settings.

Comment: are you saying even after removing email address from reserved credentials, you are not able to use email address?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server after deleting?

Comment: yes i restarted the server.. still facing the same issue